Fixed Effects vs. Random Effects in Panel Data with a Time-Invariant Main Variable
I’m working with panel data and planning to use a fixed-effects model. However, my primary variable of interest is time-invariant, which I can't include in a fixed-effects model.
I have two questions:

Would it be appropriate to use a random-effects model instead? Should I conduct a Hausman test first to determine whether random effects would be suitable?

If I need to run the Hausman test, I’m unsure how to proceed because I can’t create two identical models for comparison (fixed effects vs. random effects), given that the fixed-effects model omits the time-invariant variable. How should I address this issue?


Thanks!

You have a couple of options here.

You can include a time-invariant variable in a fixed effects model as long as you interact it with a time-varying variable. That works because the time-varying variable's value changes every year (or for every firm or whatever your panel variable is) and thus it's value on the interaction variable (time_varying*time_invariant) also changes. Note that you cannot get a "main effect" coefficient for the cluster-level variable in this approach.
You can run your random effects model as a so-called correlated random effects model or a Mundlak (1978) model in which you run a random effects model that includes the group mean for each of the time-invariant variables. See this excellent answer to a prior CV question on this topic.
I am not sure what software you are using, but an easy way to approximate the Hausman test is to run the Mundlak model suggested in #2 and then run a joint Wald test that all the mean-level predictors are equal to 0. This is a test of whether there are differential between and within cluster effects for the set of variables included in your model* and the test follows a $\chi^2$ distribution. If it is significant, then you have endogeneity in the predictors of interest and depending on your field, may have to make an argument for your model of choice.

*Note that the variables I am referring to here are all the time-varying variables in your model. Do not include the time-invariant variables in the model when you run this test.
